# Set Folder Permission with icacls

Tags: powershell, permissions, icacls

I am embarrased that I have to ask this, but  as the syntax of `icacls` apparently has changed in powershell, I seem to be unable to assemble a working command.

**What I am trying to do:**

I want to remove all permissions from a specific folder and then add the "Current logged on user" and "SYSTEM" to have Full Control. But not Admins or anything else.

**What I have:**

```
icacls $MyFolder /inheritance:r /grant: $Domain\Env:Username:(OI)(CI)F /T /grant: SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

But everytime when I execute the command I get an error

> (OI)(CI) /T has not been recognized as a cmdlet or command...

I have read some tricks on the internet to use different kind of quotes or backticks for the parameters, but nothing worked for me.

Can anyone please tell my what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've hinted at, the issue here isn't that the syntax is `icacls` has changed in PowerShell but rather that PowerShell can act strangely when executing an external command (executable) that takes arguments.

There's several ways to handle arguments, one of which is to pass them as an array of strings:

```
$IcaclsArgs = @(
    $MyFolder,
    "/inheritance:r",
    "/grant",
    "$Domain\$($Env:Username):(OI)(CI)F",
    "/T",
    "/grant",
    "SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F",
    "/T"
)

& icacls @IcaclsArgs
```

Comment: Wow, once again thx alot for your super quick answer Mark! This is really strange. In that case I will handle the permissions with a seperate CMD script. Would have just been nice to have everything within one script :)

Comment: I just noticed in your code also you put `Env:username` where you probably meant `$env:username` (and it would also need to be within a `$()` ). Just FYI.

Comment: The names of [automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) like `$args` should be avoided for "normal" variables. I'd also recommend using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) for passing the array to the command. Shouldn't make a difference with executables, but functions or scriptblocks will behave differently if you don't splat the argument array.